# Нужен совет с помощью чего сверстать вот такой блок?

Tags: html, css

Надо сверстать вот [image: пример]

Не знаю как обозвать такой изгиб, что бы загуглить:) И как его верстать? С помощью чего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.cutout {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 12px solid blue;
    border-top-left-radius: 60px 90px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 60px 90px;
}
```

Comment: а как быть с внутренней стороной: там есть сероватый полу-фон, как его реализовать?

Comment: Добавить box-shadow

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое и быстрое поставить картинку на фон. Если так не хочется, то можно попробовать комбо `border-radius`, `transform`.

Comment: буду пробовать через border-radius, transform. А как это назвать вообще: изгиб, кривая или ?